# react run android display "babel:config:config-chain" errors and not run app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

After new installation by running command

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

The command "react-native run-android" display lot of "babel:config:config-chain" messages and the app not run ...

```
babel:config:config-chain Ignored '/home/argaz/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/JSTransformer/worker.js' because it failed to match one of [ /^\/home\/argaz\/AwesomeProject\/node_modules\/react-native\/local-cli/,
babel:config:config-chain   /^\/home\/argaz\/AwesomeProject\/node_modules\/react-native\/local-cli/ ] from '/home/argaz/AwesomeProject' +125ms
babel:config:config-chain Ignored '/home/argaz/AwesomeProject/node_modules/metro/src/ModuleGraph/worker/JsFileWrapping.js' because it failed to match one of [ /^\/home\/argaz\/AwesomeProject\/node_modules\/react-native\/local-cli/,
```

More informations :

- react v16.6.3
- react-native v0.57.8
- node v10.1.2

Anyone encounter this problem ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel logs that output when the `DEBUG` environment variable is set to something like `*`, or something more specific like `babel:*`, `babel:config:*` or `babel:config:config-chain`. Something in your build system must be setting that variable.